# Can circumcision cause childhood masturbation?

Tags: penis, masturbation, sexual-arousal

Before I start, let me say I hope this question isn't marked as seeking personal medical advice because I'm not asking for medical advice, and even though I talk about my personal experiences, I just want to know if circumcision can lead to early childhood masturbation.

I was circumcised when I was about 3 or 4 and I can't remember at which age I started masturbating so my guess is that it started right after that (very early). For as long as I can remember, I've always had a sensetive penis and I think that led to early masturbation. I could always feel slight stimulation whenever I lied down towards the bed.

Also I wonder if this has anything to do with being "cut tight".

Comment: One thing is for sure, there's no clear cut answer to "does circumcision lead to early childhood masturbation". For me personally it didn't (I'm circumcised and I didn't masturbate as a child), so it means each person act in different ways. I don't think your question is dupe since the main issue for you is the early masturbation and not sensitivity of penis, but I'm not a mod here so won't change their decision. If you can edit the question, remove the part of sensitivity and leave only early masturbation question then it might get reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The question would still be closed as medical advice and for lack of prior research.